# Nested AND/OR IF functions for excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

```
=IF(AND(E4=F4, OR(E4="YES", F4="YES")), "Yes", IF(OR(E4="MAYBE",F4="MAYBE"),"Maybe","No"),"No")
```

Does anyone know how to fix this for excel? I have tried many things that aren't working.
I am essentially trying to say :
If both cells are equal to each other and are yes, then yes, if one cell has a maybe then maybe, else no.

Comment: Use: `=IF(AND(E4=F4,E4="Yes"),E4,IF(COUNTIF(E4:F4,"Maybe"),"Maybe","No"))`

Answer (score 0):

Is the error message from Excel 2013 not saying enough?
[image]
(Sorry i do not know if other version of EXcel give such nice warnings... )

The function `IF(` can only have 3 parameters. The first one is evaluated for True of False, and if True the second parameter is returned, otherwise the third parameter.

And you seem to have four parameters in your `IF`...

BTW: Next time if you ask such a question, include the error message.

Comment: Thank you, i did get this error message once but i fixed it afterwards, the biggest issue was it asking if i meant to use a function. Sorry first time user on here, will keep in mind for next time

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that your topmost IF statement has four parameters instead of three.
It worked for me after removing last "No":

```
=IF(AND(E4=F4, OR(E4="YES", F4="YES")), "Yes", IF(OR(E4="MAYBE",F4="MAYBE"),"Maybe","No"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had been staring at this for too long to see the issue!